# Current page highlighted in menu

Tags: html, css, menu

I'm trying to get my menu to highlight the current selected page from that menu.

http://jsfiddle.net/ePtFq/

My HTML code looks like so:

```
<div class="menu-container">
    <div class="menu-wrapper">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li class="current"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">PHOTOS</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Firstly, **is this the proper way** of doing the `highlight the current page in menu`? The plan is for each html page to have the `class="current"` manually changed to that respective page.

Secondly, how do I get the format to change? What **order** does the `#menu`, `li` and `.current` have to appear in? I've tried:

```
#menu li .current{
    background: #f00;
}
```

But no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the space between `li` and `.current`.

`#menu li .current` means "any element of class `.current` inside a `li` inside `#menu`."

`#menu li.current` means "`li` of class `.current` inside `#menu`."

And yes, it's OK to add `class="current"` to the current menu item on each page.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space between `li` and `.current`.

```
#menu li.current{
    background: #f00;
}
```

When you're targeting an element with a specific class, the class should always come directly after the element. If not, you're targeting any child element of the element that has the specified class.

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/ePtFq/1/

OR
used JS

```
 $(document).ready(function (e) {
            var page = top.location.toString().split('/');
            $('#menu').find('a[href="' + page[page.length - 1].toString() + '"]').closest('li').addClass('current');
        });
```

Comment: This may work, but it's gonna bring many headaches for someone who's just starting and wants to learn basic CSS selector usage. You didn't even explain what it does and why you'd recommend this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple Javascript

```
function LoadCurrentMenu()
    {
        var str=location.href.toLowerCase();
        $("#menu li a").each(function() {
            if (str.indexOf($(this).attr("href").toLowerCase()) > -1) {
                $("li.current").removeClass("current");
                $(this).parent().addClass("current");
            }
        });
        $("li.current").parents().each(function(){
            if ($(this).is("li")){
                $(this).addClass("current");
            }
        });
     }
```

and call this function on body load event like below

```
<body onload="LoadCurrentMenu();">
</body>
```